# Listen to Google Sheet from Java

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I've been accessing Google Sheets from Java and have been able to read and write to Sheets. Now I am in a position where I would like to be able to observe a sheet and get a notification when there is a change in the document. At the moment I consider setting up a scheduled task that polls the sheet to see if changes have been done. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the way to go is by using the Google Drive API where you can listen to file changes: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the API, it doesn't look like there's any sort of event or listener system in place. It looks like [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) API from google has events and listeners, so you might be able to make some cross communication, or a simple program from the API to forward events to your Java application through a web protocol. (Since the API is Javascript)

Comment: I don't know how to make a program to forward events from the API as of now. Seems I will have to do polling from the backend. Wouldn't that be better than writing a small program in Javascript?